# How do I bulk delete contacts?

Tags: contacts

Is there a way to bulk delete contacts? I don't see a way out of the box of civicrm to select contacts individually form a report or search result, the way that views bulk operations does in drupal (with the checkboxes in front of contacts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yuri. You can do this from ANY search option. Delete Contacts or Delete Permanently are options under ACTIONS. You can verify this on the demo site. If you do not see same options on your system I would start by looking at the Permissions

Comment: as mentioned in the question, I want to select the contacts from a list by ticking checkboxes. Using search, first there needs to be search criteria, and in my experience most of the time search criteria cannot be applied, because contacts need to be selected individually for operations.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you peform a search, even with no criteria, then all your contacts are displayed. you can then check the box next to the people you need, as @petednz points out, and click Actions > Delete contacts. If you have a lot of contacts then you'd want to perform a search to target the ones to delete, then tick the boxes next to a selection of them.

Comment: That's the point: even as administrator, I don't see any checkboxes before the contacts when I perform a search.

Comment: Okay ...if found it: I was using the search block in the left column, which apparently has a simple search result without checkboxes. Using the search from the administration menu did show a result  with checkboxex. Thank you.