# Bulk Delete of Spam Contacts and related Drupal Users

Tags: contacts, delete

I've a list of 8K+ CiviCRM contacts that have been deemed spam/unwanted. I am looking to clear them from CiviCRM, along with their related Drupal users.

I've found and tested this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/userdelete which will allow me to plug in a list of email addresses, arrived at from joining my list of contacts to the civicrm_uf_match table.

My question is, what is the path of least resistance to handle a clean removal of the CiviCRM contacts?

The API explorer seems to indicate that the contact delete method will only take a single contact id at a time, which would force me to write a module or a rest client to iterate through my list.

Would simply updating the CiviCRM DB directly with is_deleted = 1 do the trick?

I imagine this isn't a new situation...

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Have you tried Search functionality such as "Find Contacts", "Advanced Search", etc? You can find delete contact in the action menu. Also see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4518/how-do-i-bulk-delete-contacts?rq=1

Comment: The spam contact list has been compiled via some complex logic and conditions directly via SQL query, the list is not something I can just plug in to a basic GUI search.

Comment: You can add a temporary tag / group with an import from their CiviCRM IDs to make them searchable in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Drupal, you can install the CiviCRM Entity module, and use Views Bulk Operations to create a View that will delete contacts, or any CiviCRM data in a Drupal Batch API process

Comment: You'll need the submodule CiviCRM Entity Actions enabled as well